# How do you set compile flags in CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, command-line

I'm writing a project using the Slate linear algebra library in C++, with MKL, MPI and OpenMP as dependencies. Usually, I run my program on a Linux based system with

```
$ mpicxx -fopenmp -Wall -std=c++17 -MMD -I/opt/slate/include -DSLATE_NO_CUDA  -c -o test.o test.cpp
$ mpicxx -o test test.o -fopenmp -L/opt/slate/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/slate/lib  -lslate -lblaspp -llapackpp
```

However, recently I wanted to try out CMake, but I can't get it to work correctly.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

# set the project name and version
project(1D_DFT VERSION 0.1)

#Slate directories
set(slate_dir /opt/slate)

#Compiler and libraries
set(CXXFLAGS  -fopenmp -Wall -std=c++17 -MMD -I${slate_dir}/include -DSLATE_NO_CUDA)
set(LDFLAGS   -fopenmp -L${slate_dir}/lib -Wl,-rpath,${slate_dir}/lib)
set(LIBS      -lslate -lblaspp -llapackpp)

#Setting compiler
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CXXFLAGS})
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS ${LDFLAGS} ${LIBS})

add_library(test.o OBJECT test.cpp)

#Add the executable
add_executable(1D_DFT $<TARGET_OBJECTS:test.o>)

SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(
        $<TARGET_OBJECTS:test.o>
        PROPERTIES
        GENERATED true
```

It doesn't recognise any of the compiler or linker flags! How does one tell CMake to run with a specific set of flags?

Comment: If you're trying to look for "Make" documentation and apply what you learn to "CMake", that really won't work.  Use "CMake" in all your searches to find the relevant information.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! According to [the CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS.html), you should  quote multiple options. Also, when asking a question, always consider writing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: CMake has separate functions  to set libraries and include directories along with the c++ standard. You should not do any of these by setting compiler flags.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by LHLaurini in the comments, you should use quotes around the flags when assigning them to variables. If you don't, CMake will turn them into a semicolon-delimited list and mess up the commands. Here's an example of how to do it correctly:

```
set(CXXFLAGS  "-fopenmp -Wall -std=c++17 -MMD -I${slate_dir}/include -DSLATE_NO_CUDA")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CXXFLAGS}")
```

More importantly, however, writing CMake files involves a very different paradigm from writing Makefiles. Modern best practices would recommend setting flags and libraries as properties of specific targets. Here's a [presentation](https://youtu.be/eC9-iRN2b04) I would recommend to learn more about this paradigm. If you apply these design principles to your CMake code, it comes out looking more like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

# set the project name and version
project(1D_DFT VERSION 0.1)

#Slate directories
set(slate_dir /opt/slate)

add_executable(1D_DFT test.cpp)
target_compile_definitions(1D_DFT PRIVATE SLATE_NO_CUDA)
target_compile_features   (1D_DFT PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
target_compile_options    (1D_DFT PRIVATE -fopenmp -Wall)
target_include_directories(1D_DFT PRIVATE ${slate_dir}/include)
target_link_directories   (1D_DFT PRIVATE ${slate_dir}/lib)
target_link_libraries     (1D_DFT PRIVATE slate blaspp lapackpp)
set_property(TARGET 1D_DFT PROPERTY BUILD_RPATH "${slate_dir}/lib")
```